# asp:BoundField view the values with a condition

Tags: asp.net, boundfield

i have a dataview with:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="AccontoAutorizzato" HeaderText="Acconto Aut." 
                        SortExpression="AccontoAutorizzato" dataformatstring="{0:C}"  />
```

is possible hide the values of each with a condition like

```
 Visible=<%# ((Int32)Eval("StatoID") < 2) %>
```

?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible with following

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Acconto Aut." >
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AccontoAutorizzato") %>'
                        Visible='<%# ((int)(Eval("StatoID")) < 2) %>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I am surprised this worked. I have another alternative answered below.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Right @TobySpeight! The solution is to actually avoid using the BoundField because it does not support binding for the visibility. TemplateField however, does.

Answer (score 1):

[Saar's answer](/a/1839212) did not work for me, because even though the binding should return a true or false, the interpreter could not actually convert the condition result to a Boolean value.

So instead, I used an explicit choice of `Boolean` values:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Acconto Aut." >
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind"AccontoAutorizzato") %>'
                        Visible='<%# ((int)(Eval("StatoID")) < 2) ? Convert.ToBoolean(0) : Convert.ToBoolean(1) %>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I hope this makes it easier for others struggling with the Boolean error when applying it to a Visible property.