# conditionally show hide asp.net Gridview column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, visible

This is how I navigate to `myPage.aspx` ,

```
<a href='~/myPage.aspx?show=<%#Eval("id")%>' id="showEach" runat="server">Show Each</a>

<a href="~/myPage.aspx?show=all" id="showAll" runat="server">Show All</a>
```

And I have a gridview in `myPage.aspx`

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField  HeaderText="ColumnOne"  Visible="true"/>
<asp:BoundField  HeaderText="ColumnTwo"  Visible="true"/>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

What I want to do is , if Query String is equal to `all`(~/myPage.aspx?show=all) , I want to set GridView1's `Column2`'s visible to true , else , set visible to false .
How can I do it ?

Comment: how and where you bind data in gridview?

Comment: it's not depends on `datasource` of my gridview AmitSingh , it's depends on `QueryString` !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GridView Hide Column by code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819247/gridview-hide-column-by-code)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use gridview column index to hide the particular column

Code could be

```
 if(Request.QueryString.Get("show")=="all")
    GridView1.Columns[1].Visible=true;
 else
    GridView1.Columns[1].Visible=false;
```

More detail

[GridView Hide Column by code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819247/gridview-hide-column-by-code)

### Edit 3

## Settings in ASPX/ASCX can not be done directly.

<%= %> outputs directly to the response stream, and the asp markup is not part of the response stream. Its a mistake to assume the <%= %> operators are performing any kind of preprocessing on the asp markup.

More explanation

[Why will <%= %> expressions as property values on a server-controls lead to a compile errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370201/why-will-expressions-as-property-values-on-a-server-controls-lead-to-a-co)

### Edit 1

I think yes

```
 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ColumnTwo" 
      Visible='<% if (Request.QueryString.Get("all") == "all" ) "true" else "false" %>'/>
```

**You will have to check for the syntex**

### Edit 2

Try this

```
 Visible='<% Request.QueryString.Get("all") == "all"? "true": "false"%>'
```

Comment: Is there any way likes > `<asp:BoundField  HeaderText="ColumnTwo"  Visible='if(Request.QueryString[show])==all{....}else{....}'/>`

Comment: Yes Shekhar , it's said `This expression is not a valid statement` :)

Answer (score 11):

You can use gridview pre-render method to set this...

```
protected void GridView_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Reqest.QueryString["Id"]=="all"&& Reqest.QueryString["Id"]!=null)
         {
           GridViewId.Columns[1].Visible = true;
         }
        else
            GridViewId.Columns[1].Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: Is there any way likes > `<asp:BoundField  HeaderText="ColumnTwo"  Visible='if(Request.QueryString[show])==all){....}else{....}'/>`

Comment: you should be using '==' rather than '='

Answer (score 1):

Dear try to use [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event of Grid View like

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //here apply your condition
        if(Request.QueryString["name"] == "all")
        e.Row.Cells[<index_of_cell>].Visible = true;
        else
        e.Row.Cells[<index_of_cell>].Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Try something like that.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Is there any way likes > `<asp:BoundField  HeaderText="ColumnTwo"  Visible='if(Request.QueryString[show])==all{....}else{....}'/>`

Comment: the way you want to bind is possible but not in bound field, have to use ItemTemplate check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839163/aspboundfield-view-the-values-with-a-condition .have to do something like that.